# How do i make this calculation in qb64 (1 / (2.718282 ^ 110)) + 1 to get the right answer?

Tags: qb64

How do i make this calculation in qb64 (1 / (2.718282 ^ 110)) + 1 to get the right answer? Because it keep tells me the answer is 1.

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: 1,000000 something bigger than 1

Answer (score 2):

`e^110` is a very large number. Therefore, `1/(e^110)` is very close to zero. Adding `1`, you get the same result as `qb64`.

Ask [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%20%2F%20(2.718282%20%5E%20110))%20%2B%201) for confirmation.

[image]

`QuickBasic` is probably rounding down due to limited accuracy.

Comment: I know but maybe there is a way with DIM m AS _MEM to make a bigger accuracy

Comment: I don't have `QuickBasic` to experiment. You could try to convert all operands to `DOUBLE` using the `CDBL()` conversion function. This should improve accuracy. As far as I know, the `^` operator works with `DOUBLE` precision anyhow. But without a library for infinite precision, there will always be some rounding.

Comment: Nope it gives me 1/2.718282^110 = 1.688900156341D-4B but when i add 1 the answer is still 1

Comment: The first part of your expression is `1.688E-48`, Therefore, the result requires more than `49` significant digits. This is far beyond of what any pocket caclulator or normal single/double float arithmetic can express.

Comment: Since the default precision of a variable in QB is single then your accuracy is going to be 7 digits. If declared as double it will become 15 digits. Any number of 0s to the right of the decimal place is beyond that then it it be rounded to .0 and adding 1 returns 1.

Comment: The ! operator indicates single precision whereas the # operator indicates double precision. Unique to QB64 the ## operator indicates float precision.